# C# Draw when window is loaded

Tags: c#, load, window

I want to draw some ellipses when the window is `loaded` without clicking anything, how can I do it?
My code is the following :

```
        int kerX = random.Next(10,281);
        int kerY = random.Next(10,281);
        mrPainter.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, kerX + 10, kerY + 10, 20, 20);
        mrPainter.FillEllipse(blue,65,65,20,20);
        mrPainter.FillEllipse(red, 205, 65, 20, 20);
        mrPainter.FillEllipse(yellow, 135, 215, 20, 20);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your are using WinForms, simply insert the code in the `FormLoaded` event of your main form.

Comment: @jony No problem. Since my answer helped you, please mark it as the solution by clicking the check mark. Optionally, you can also upvote if you want to.